# Training Model and then Predicting regressions of grouped variables at once

Tags: r, dplyr, regression, plyr

I have a dataset that has many different groupings of variables.  I also have a test set that may OR may NOT have all of the same groups.

What I want to do is for each subset/group of the train set, run a regression and then apply it to the appropriate matching group in the test set.

I tried to get started doing this in Plyr but this package is a little confusing to me.

```
    library(plyr)
    data = mtcars # use this as easy example


    my_regressions = plyr::dlply(mtcars, plyr::.(vs,am),lm,formula= mpg ~ wt+cyl)
```

If I had another dataset how would I apply the PREDICT function to the appropriate group?    I tried to figure this out in DPlyr which is preferred but I couldn't.  Any help ?:(

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using `lapply` with `predict`, like this:

```
lapply(
dlply(mtcars, .(vs,am), lm, formula = "mpg ~ wt+cyl"),
predict)
```

Comment: Yes, I see how this works, but sorry what I want to be able to save each of the individual regression models buitl and apply it to another dataset with the matching groups?  For instance a mtcars_test?

Comment: Then after `predict` add `,newdata=mtcars_test`

Comment: I appreciate the support, but the ddply stuff with lists confuses the hell out of me.   I can get predicts this way but it seems to be when I call do.call(OUTCOME, cbind)   I get a table that contains of each of the combination of regression models outcomes rather than the corresponding one.   For example if a Car in the dataset was 1/1 with VS and Am  I will get regression output in a table with all 4 combination of predictions.  Anyway for just a corresponding prediction and all in 1 column?   I much prefer Dplyr than plyr since lists confuse me again  but I can't find much reference on it